# django RDF support?

Tags: django, rdf, sparql, semantic-web, triplestore

I'm looking for a tool that would help to provide RDF support to Django projects.

So far I've found two:

- [django-rdf](http://code.google.com/p/django-rdf/) - last modification was 4 yesrs ago so it looks like a dead project.
- [djubby](http://code.google.com/p/djubby/) - looks like a all-or-nothing project - either you create your django app as a completely RDF oriented software, without any other urls or you just can't use it.

I'm looking for some other alternatives, do you know any?

Answer (score 4):

I'm no Python/Django person but here are a few links. Also it would help if you could detail a bit more what you mean by "support": rdf parsing? Sparql processing? link to a triple store? Microformats? something else?

Similar question: [djangonic way to deal with rdf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11365796/djangonic-way-to-deal-with-rdf)

Not on Django itself but Python, you might find something: http://www.michelepasin.org/blog/2011/02/24/survey-of-pythonic-tools-for-rdf-and-linked-data-programming/

You can also find some info here also http://semanticdjango.org/

some project on github: https://github.com/odeoncg/django-rdflib

Comment: I mean something that will provide SPARQL interface to my django application model.

Comment: how's your model persisted? do you use a DB or do you want to use a triplestore? or do you want something custom?

Comment: and do you just want to provide a sparql endpoint to your data from oracle or do you want to do something else? (sorry if I appear annoying with my questions, I'm just trying to understand better)

Comment: Ideally I would like to provide a sparcle endpoint to my django model, regardless of underlying db backend. It's OK, you can ask :)

Comment: I looked a bit and didn't really find anything that would do that. In general it looks to me like quite a difficult task to implement. you want performance in a sparql server so that's why there are triple store. Imagine the same saying "i want to provide a sql query interface to my model"... Maybe using a specific triple store could do. and in this case, you could map it using a object-rdf mapper...

Answer (score 2):

Theres a couple of different issues here.

You could use http://d2rq.org/ to provide a SPARQL endpoint to your database. (Seems to be what you're looking for based on a comment above and its less circuitous than rdb->django model->rdf->sparql )

You could use surf as an ORM layer to put data into django templates.

You could add rdfa into your templates

The django apps that you point to are useful as an example (eg. for redirection, interfacing with triplestores etc.)

Answer (score 2):

Having searched around and found only various project corpses I have started a project with a different approach to any of these mentioned: it is a django project to configure a custom RDF serialisation of Django models. This allows elements of a model, and models related to it, to be mapped to RDF predicates.

Its at https://github.com/rob-metalinkage/django-rdf-io
and used in https://github.com/rob-metalinkage/django-skosxl

Currently working on interfacing to Linked Data Platform (LDP) containers with reasoners to generate a full set statements - e.g. compute transitive relationships.